# Typing L with stroke (Ł) with US international dead keys layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

US international with dead keys under Linux seems to be perfect for typing most of the accented characters. Recently however I was unable to find a valid combination for typing the “*L with stroke*” (**Ł** or **ł**). I don't seem to find it in the [layout](http://dry.sailingissues.com/us-international-keyboard-layout.html). Is there a way to obtain **Ł** out of the box?

**Edit**: Anything simpler than going through the compose key?